# Can't initialize attribute for object

Tags: python, object

For some reason I cannot initialize an attribute(volume) with my data class.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp
import datetime
import time

class Data:

    def __init__(self,volume):
        self.volume = volume
    
    def responce(self):
        r = requests.get('https://robinhood.com/stocks/WISH') ///START OF REQUEST
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        semigoal = [x.text for x in soup.select('span.css-ktio0g')] ///PARSING INFORMATION
        goal = str(semigoal[11])
        goal = [char for char in goal]
        goaltext= ""
        for x in goal:
            goaltext += x
        goal = goal[0:(len(goal)-1)]
        volume = ""
        for x in goal:
            volume += x /// END OF PARSING
        print(volume) ///PRINT STATEMENT TO CHECK FUNCTIONALITY
        self.volume(self,volume)
    
d = Data()
d.responce()
```

I just would like to initialize the attribute but have a seperat function deal with the request and parsing. However I cannot figure out how to make it work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but shouldn't you be passing `volume` to `Data()`? The constructor of your class does not seem to have a default value for `volume`.

Comment: So i need to pass it into the class as well as into the function?

Comment: Passing it only to the class will do just fine, but that will have some consequences in the rest of your code that will depend on what you are trying to achieve. For example: you are probably initializing `volume` in your constructor method to use it in your method(function of your class), so you can write in `responce` function `volume=self.volume` instead of `volume=''`. Doing that way you won't change the value of self.volume each time you need to call the `responce` method.

Comment: The only thing I can't understand is the last line of the `responce` method: `self.volume(self,volume)`.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: So essentially, I was trying to create an object which will be a stock. Then I want to create several attributes to store to that object. So I initialized my object, then I wanted a function to handle the get request and parsing data. Then all I want is to assign the attribute self.volume to the volume I get from the response function. However I just cant figure out how too.

Comment: Just change the last line of your responce function to `self.volume = volume`.